# jQuery toggle div if var equals value doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, toggle, show-hide

I have a page whose layout is fairly simple: A button on top #show_likes toggles all liked posts. All posts (in a foreach loop) contains a button with class of .like (the like button). When .like is pressed it is liked. For now lets assume this is permanent.

I have a variable likestatus which tracks the number of times #show_likes is pressed. When likestatus divided by 2 has no remainder, that means all liked posts should be hidden. If there is a remainder, all liked posts should be visible. Pretty straight forward right?

On page load, likestatus is set to 1 and since 1 divded by 2 has a remainder, all liked posts are hidden on pageload. This works in both firefox AND chrome.

Because likestatus is set to 1, all posts the user decides to like SHOULD toggle automatically. This works in firefox BUT NOT chrome.

The question is, why?

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    likestatus = 1; //on pageload, likestatus is 1 so all liked posts are hidden.

$(document).on("click", ".like", function(){                //when like button is pressed do this
    postID = $(this).attr('id').replace('like_', '');       // get the ID of the post

    // Declare variables
    value = '1';                                            //this represents that the post is liked to be stored in a database

    myajax();                                               //send to database

    return false;
});

function myajax(){                                          // Send values to database
    $.ajax({
        url: 'check.php',                                   //check.php receives the values sent to it and stores them in the database
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'postID=' + postID + '&value=' + value,       //send the post ID and like value
        success: function(result) {
            if (result.indexOf("No") < 0){                  //If return doesn't contain string "No", do this
                if (value == 1){                            //If post is liked, do this
                    $('#post-' + postID).removeClass('dislike').addClass('like');               //sets div class of the post to liked
                    $('#likebtn_' + postID).removeClass('likeimgoff').addClass('likeimgon');        //changes the image of the like button so it is visibly activated

// UP TO HERE, THE CODE WOKS IN BOTH CHROME AND FIREFOX. IN CHROME, THE CODE BELOW DOESN'T WORK

                // If Hide Liked button is on, toggle the post
                if (likestatus % 2 == 0) {
                } else {
                    $('#post-' + postID).toggle();
                }
            } 
        }
    }
});
}

// THE CODE BELOW WORKS IN BOTH CHROME AND FIREFOX

$('#show_likes').on('click', function() { //When Hide Liked checkbox clicked, toggle all liked posts.
    likestatus++; //increment likestatus

    if (likestatus % 2 == 0) {
        $('#hidelikedbtn').removeClass('hidelikedimgoff').addClass('hidelikedimgon'); // changes the image of the hide all liked button so it is visibly deactivated
    } else {
        $('#hidelikedbtn').removeClass('hidelikedimgon').addClass('hidelikedimgoff'); // changes the image of the hide all liked button so it is visibly activated
    }

return false;
});
```

index.php

```
<?php global $post; ?>

<div id="show_likes">
   <a id="hidelikedbtn" class="hidelikedimgoff mstrctrlL" href="#"><span></span>    </a>
</div>

<?php foreach ($pageposts as $post): ?>

<?php setup_postdata($post);
        $msg_id= $post->ID; 
?>

<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="post <?php post_class(); ?>">
    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>-inside" class="inside">
        <h2 class="posttitle">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php _e( 'Permanent Link to', 'buddypress' ) ?> <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </h2>

        <div id="like_<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="like">
                <a id="likebtn_<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="likeimgoff" href="#"><span></span></a>
            </div>

        <div class="entry">
            <?php the_content( __( 'Read the rest of this entry &rarr;', 'buddypress' ) ); ?>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- post-ID-inside -->
</div> <!-- post-ID -->
```

When I change $('#post-' + postID).toggle() to $('#post-' + postID).css("visibility","hidden"); it works (albeit the post is simply invisible instead of "gone"). Point is, the code does work all the way down to this line and the postID does get recognized but something about chrome just won't let the toggle function..

Answer (score 2):

your not passing the post id

```
$(document).on("click", ".like", function(){
    postID = $(this).attr('id').replace('like_', '');

    // Declare variables
    value = '1';

    myajax(postID); //added variable

    return false;
});

function myajax(postID){  // added variable
    // Send values to database
    $.ajax({
        url: 'check.php',
        //check.php receives the values sent to it and stores them in the database
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'postID=' + postID + '&value=' + value,
        success: function(result) {
        $('#Message_' + postID).html('').html(result).prependTo('#buttons_' + postID);
                if (result.indexOf("No") < 0){ //If return doesn't contain string "No", do this
                if (value == 1){ //If post is liked, do this
                    // If Hide Liked button is on, toggle the post
                    if (likestatus % 2 == 0) {
                    } else {
                        $('#post-' + postID).toggle();
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
```

Comment: The postID gets sent perfectly fine. I know this because the #Message is prepended to the correct place, which relies on the postID. I tried your code anyway and it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I used your code and the problem is the same - it works in firefox but not in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the line `$('#post-' + postID).toggle();` with `alert('postID');`. If the alert pops up then you know the success function hits that spot of your logic.

Assuming the alert fires, check to make sure that the `postID` contains a valid value, and that `#post-XX` is a valid `id` attribute in your markup (where "XX" is the `postID`).

Also, what happens if you call the toggle like so?

```
if ((likestatus % 2) > 0) {
    $('#post-' + postID).toggle();
}
```

Comment: postID is set perfectly fine. Like I said, the AJAX is sent without problem, the confirmation message even displays the postID that gets sent. Firefox reports that the value is valid and it is ineed and valid attribute in my markup. I've updated my code with a little more code inside the success function to show you why I know it is valid... some classes get switched and they do function (the classes change the image of the buttons. The problem is truly only with the toggling..

Comment: I noticed that my code DOES work in firefox but NOT in chrome. Any ideas why?

Comment: Could you add some sample markup to your question (like the structure for `'#post-' + postID`?

Comment: I added the markup for the posts as you requested.Again, my code does work in firefox, but not chrome for some reason.

Comment: @Jonathan do you get an error in Chrome (check the console by right-clicking on anything in the window and click "inspect element")?

Comment: @Jonathan where do you declare and initialize `likestatus`?

Comment: at the very top, second line of my code likestatuts is declared as having a value of 1. When the user clicks the hide all liked button, likestatus is incremented by 1 (see bottom of my javascript code) at which pint it equals 2. When the user clicks it again, it equals 3 since 3/2 has a remainder, posts will toggle when liked. The thing is in chrome, they don't toggle when likestatus is 1 (but it works in firefox) which is what should happen on pageload.

Comment: A thought: could it be because i'm trying to toggle while a toggle is in effect?

Comment: If I change .toggle() to .hide(), the code works in chrome. SO why won't .toggle() work?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?